# SHA256 fingerprint in hgrc

Tags: mercurial, verification, sha256, fingerprint

How can I force mercurial in .hgrc to check the SHA256 fingerprint when connecting to the repository server?

In .hgrc usually SHA1 fingerprints are used as

```
[hostfingerprints]
foo.bar.baz = a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:00:f9:r8:d7:c6
```

Using a SHA256 fingerprint would cause hg to fail to connect:

```
abort: certificate for foo.bar.baz has unexpected fingerprint 00:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:0a:0b:0c:0d:0e:0f:a1:b1:c1:d1
(check hostfingerprint configuration)
```

Does mercurial **always** expect a SHA1 here or this be done by with the client configuration at all or does this have to be set on the server side?

e.g. [openssl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140601/verifying-a-ssl-certificates-fingerprint) has `-sha1` and `-sha256` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does mercurial always expect a SHA1 here

Yes. Just re-read *actual for today* [description of hostfingerprints section](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hostfingerprints) in hgrc (bolding is my addition)

> The fingerprint is the **SHA-1 hash value** of the DER encoded certificate.

Comment: Actually mercurial allows SHA2 too, which works the same way as SHA1 and generates a longer hash. e.g. Bitbucket's cert is SHA2: https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/05/06/bitbuckets-ssl-certificate-is-changing-for-sha-2/